# SQL Server insert or query between servers ingnores column in table starting with a number?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to query between two servers which have identical tables (used the same create statement for both).  When I try to insert the results from Server A to Server B I get an error indicating "*Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.*"

**Query run on server A**

```
Insert into ServerB.Database1.dbo.Table1
Select *
from Table1
```

The error is clear, but what isn't clear is the reason that it is generated.  The definitions of the two tables are identical.  What I was finally able to isolate was a table name that starts with a numeric value is not being recognized.

When I run this on ServerA:

```
Select *
from ServerB.Database1.dbo.Table1
```

The field with the numeric value is not shown in the results set of they query.  The short term fix was to rename the field in the database, but why is this happening?

Comment: You shouldn't name objects with an initial numeral as this doesn't meet the rules for standard object identifiers and you always have to delimit the object name. Surprised SQL Server doesn't cope with this automatically though. What happens if you request the column explicitly rather than using `*`?

Comment: I know that this isnt best practice, but in this case I was working with the databases provided.  When I try to query for the column  explicitly you get _Invalid Column Name_ error message.  Strange that you can use it inside a server, but not across servers.

Comment: put brackets around the column...[1col]

Comment: Surprisingly this didn't work...

Comment: `select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Table1' ` what columns do you get back

Comment: The column is listed when you run the query above, that is why it is really strange.  Maybe an issue with the way the servers are configured...

Comment: is the collation the same for the two databases/servers?

Comment: Yes, it took me a little while to verify, but they are identical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious about the collation too, but really the answer is to wrap the object names in square brackets. i.e. SELECT [1col], [2col], [etc] FROM [1database].[2owner].[3table]. This way SQL with recognize each as an object name and not a function.

One other thing to keep in mind is to not use splat (*) in your select statement, this has potential problem of it's own. For example, you could run into an error in your Insert if the ServerA's table1 structure was change and ServerB's table one stayed the same.